# Rails 4.2.11.1 connection pool hang on synchronize

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, concurrency, timeout

Our rails app is version 4.2 and we get request timeout exception (35s) intermittently.  We used puma as our server and we are running it with 8 threads

Looking at the backtrace, it seems like the code is trying to get a connection from the connection pool

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
260         # this is correctly done double-checked locking
261         # (ThreadSafe::Cache's lookups have volatile semantics)
262         @reserved_connections[current_connection_id] || synchronize do
263           @reserved_connections[current_connection_id] ||= checkout
264         end
```

and `@reserved_connections[current_connection_id]` is nil at this point so it calls `synchronize` on line 262.

and the code eventually hung on a ruby 2.4.0 `monitor` class

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:187:in `lock'
185   def mon_enter
186     if @mon_owner != Thread.current
187       @mon_mutex.lock
188       @mon_owner = Thread.current
189       @mon_count = 0
```

^ hung on line 187 above and timeout.

I was thinking that setting `reaping_frequency` would help, but it seems like this is more of a concurrency problem instead of a bad connection problem.

Any help/hints are appreciated.

Comment: Have you fixed it?